# Fetch data from same field name in two different tables and detect which filed name we mean

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have assigned search method for my application and i have made relationship between two tables "users " table and "posts" table both of them have same field name "created_at" and when i want to fetch data that when this post has been created it will bring the date in users table created_at field not in posts table created_at field.
All i want is how to tell the system make difference between which table field name i mean .

**This date comes from created_at field in users table**
[image: This date comes from created_at field in users table]

**I wand to come date in this created_at field in posts table**
[image: I wand to come date in this created_at field in posts table]

**ListingController.php**

```
public function search(Request $request){

     $posts = Post::with(['comments','category','creator'])
                 ->join('users', 'posts.created_by', '=', 'users.id')
                 ->where('slug', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search. '%')
                 ->orWhere('users.name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search. '%')
                 ->where('status',1)->orderBy('posts.id','DESC')->paginate(5); 

         return view('front.listing',compact('posts'));

 }
```

**listing.blade.php**

```
<div class="article_date">
               by: <a href="{{ url('/author') }}/{{ $post->creator->id }}">{{ $post->creator->name }} </a> , {{$post->created_at->diffForHumans()}}
            </div>
```

Comment: 1. Why are you doing a join on user since you already have the `creator` relationship that gets the same data? 2. you can use `$post->creator->created_at->diffForHumans()`

Comment: If i don't join it i will give this error ```   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `posts` where `slug` LIKE %interesting% or `users`.`name` LIKE %interesting% and `status` = 1)  ```

Comment: You can run conditions with closure on your relationship (but that would be for another question )

Comment: then just add `->select('posts.*')` in your query

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your relationship improperly. You should not use a join there. Use [constrained eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) instead

There will be no conflict in the `created_at` date since there will be no join.
While still keeping your search query inside the closure of the relationship.

```
        $posts = Post::with(['comments', 'category'])
            ->with(['creator' => function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%');
            }])
            ->where('slug', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: I want to fetch date in posts table not users table

Comment: Error            mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: i have modified the code that u sent     .            C:\xampp\htdocs\project\news\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Str.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214399/discussion-between-andria-and-christophe-hubert).

Comment: I did , but i can't get the author's name